# How to restart BIND9 in C language(linux)?

Tags: c, linux, bind, named

I written a program to see whether the named process has dead or not,just like that:

```
char *cmd = "pidof named | wc -l";
if((fp = popen(cmd , "r")) == NULL)
{
    throw;
}
fscanf(fp,"%d",&runningNum);
pclose(fp);
```

If the runningNum=0, it indicated that no named process was running.So i want to restart the BIND process.I have tried to use `sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart` as a paramater of popen(),but it didn't work.So could you help me?

Comment: I would not restart it from your C program. Better to log (using `syslog`) the error. The user could have decided to have some other DNS service than `bind9`; I am happy using `pdnsd`

Comment: A good sysadmin won't restart such an essential service without at least understanding why the service crashed... So restarting magically from your program is really a bad idea... `named` should not crash...

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart` works when executed in the shell by the actual unpriliveged user?